# Problema en evaluación de SSIS: requiere Boolean pero evalúa como NULL

Tags: ssis

Tengo un DWH y al correr el job a la hora programada me arroja este error:

> Message Executed as user: WST0005\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 10.0.6000.29 for 32-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started: 
>   9:50:01 PM  Error: 2018-03-20 21:55:12.31     Code: 0xC020902B
>   Source: DIM_REGION Logical SCD [117]     Description: The expression
>   "(SRC_CODIGO == DWH_CODIGO) && (SRC_DESCRIPCION != DWH_DESCRIPCION ||
>   SRC_PAIS != DWH_CD_PAIS || SRC_ID_PAIS != DWH_ID_PAIS)" on "output
>   "SCD1" (141)" evaluated to NULL, but the "component "Logical SCD"
>   (117)" requires a Boolean results. Modify the error row disposition on
>   the output to treat this result as False (Ignore Failure) or to
>   redirect this row to the error output (Redirect Row).  The expression
>   results must be Boolean for a Conditional Split.  A NULL expression
>   result is an error.  End Error  Error: 2018-03-20 21:55:12.31
>   Code: 0xC0209029     Source: DIM_REGION Logical SCD [117]
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. 
>   The "component "Logical SCD" (117)" failed because error code
>   0xC020902B occurred, and the error row disposition on "output "SCD1"
>   (141)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified
>   object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information about the failure.  End Error 
>   Error: 2018-03-20 21:55:12.31     Code: 0xC0047022     Source:
>   DIM_REGION SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component
>   "Logical SCD" (117) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing
>   input "Conditional Split Input" (118). The identified component
>   returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific
>   to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow
>   task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.  End Error  DTExec: The
>   package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  9:50:01 PM 
>   Finished: 9:55:36 PM  Elapsed:  335.64 seconds.  The package execution
>   failed.  The step failed.

No entiendo por qué me lanza el error si yo tengo este paquete inhabilitado. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme? ¿Cómo puedo corregir este error desde SSIS?

Comment: Hola Rass, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre nosotros y ganar una nueva medalla). Esta pregunta es interesante, pero quizás sería mejor tener algo más de información: el código que falla (aunque aparece en el mensaje) y los valores de las variables implicadas (según el error, una expresión que debería ser booleana es null). Saludos.

Comment: Este problema lo heredé, soy nuevo en la oficina y no hay documentacion al respecto. El job se encarga de llamar una paquete principal de ssis que engloba otros paquetes de dimensiones, la dimension que arroja el error esta inhabilidata osea que no deberia dar error, quiero saber si puedo excluirla del proyecto. ya que no esta en uso.